# element wise comparison for tensorflow tensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to do something like

```
a1=np.zeros((1,2))
a2=np.zeros((1,2))
a1==a2
```

output:

```
array([[ True,  True]])
```

but with tensors

Notice: I am making this for a keras loss function ,so I cannot convert it to a numpy array and reconvert it to a tensor
, thank you

Comment: This Keras issue from 2016 says `==` was already present then: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/4182 - are you sure it isn't supported out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for "element wise comparison" which is documented here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/comparison_operators

In your case:

```
tf.equal(a1, a2)
```